# Manage "liked" pages shown on Facebook news feed

Tags: facebook

The news feed on my iPhone Facebook includes updates from my "liked" pages, but my desktop Facebook does not. I have two questions pertaining to this discrepancy:

1. How do you show updates from "liked" pages on desktop Facebook?
2. How do you see a list of all your "liked" pages to remove the ones you don't like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage your pages by going to your **'Profile'** and clicking on **'Info'** on the left.
It lists out all the pages you have 'liked' sorted by category.
There is a edit link on the right over there.
You can remove the pages which you don't like over there.

Regarding how to show updates from the pages you've liked, I think facebook automatically hides updates from the pages you don't interact with.

Answer (score -1):

You can also find some apps to unlike your liked pages here is a tutorial for [unlike inactive pages](http://www.protechlover.com/2014/01/how-to-unlike-inactive-pages.html%E2%80%8E)

Goto the website mentioned in the link and login with your facebook id and you will get a sorted list and will be helpful too.

Comment: Please don't just link to a tutorial. This site is for providing actual answers.